# Joined 2 tables on ID which works fine, but now I want to echo the ID of the other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, reference

I have 2 tables that have been joined using the ID that correlates the data on both tables.
I output the information perfectly.

I output ID and it returns that of the ID column in table_1 - PERFECT.
But now I want to output the ID column in table_2 within the same statement.

How do I now say ID from table_2, not table_1?

Here's some code...

```
$who = $_SESSION['who'];

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_messages INNER JOIN tbl_users ON     tbl_messages.from_user = tbl_users.id WHERE tbl_messages.to_user = $who")

 or die(mysql_error()); 

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 echo "From:" . $info['id'];
 echo "to:" . $info['id'];
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one good way to do this is to say

```
SELECT tbl_messages.id as msgID, tbl_users.id as usrID, * FROM tbl_messages INNER JOIN tbl_users ON     tbl_messages.from_user = tbl_users.id WHERE tbl_messages.to_user = $who
```

Then you will reference the fields with that name

```
echo "From:" . $info['msgID'];
 echo "to:" . $info['usrID'];
```

Comment: Ah, you did it. Further more - it actually works! (Providing I remove the asterisk  * from the statement)

Comment: It didn't work without the asterisk? Interesting... what server are you running to host your database?

Comment: It gave an error when the asterisk was left in, yes. But this might be due to the fact I'm using localhost and running everything on my own computer?